# Pi 3B+ aarch64 conda illegal instruction

Tags: pi-3b+, 64-bit

I just installed [2021-05-07-raspios-buster-arm64-lite](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/raspios_lite_arm64-2021-05-28/) on my Raspberry Pi 3B+.

`uname -a` outputs:

> Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v8+ #1421 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 27 14:01:37
> BST 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux

But after installing `Miniconda3`  ([Miniconda3 Linux-aarch64 64-bit](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.10.1-Linux-aarch64.sh)) each call of `conda` and `pip` simply outputs `Illegal instruction`. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Please edit in the output from `file $(which pip)`.

Comment: @goldilocks ok, the problem is in conda `/home/pi/miniconda3/bin/pip`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just noticed `pip` is a python script, so that won't solve the mystery.   You could try `strace pip ...` and see where it fails.  You may need to `apt install strace`.

Comment: To clarify: the *illegal instruction* means there's an executable being invoked that is compiled for the wrong ISA (aarch64).  `file` on an executable would reveal what it is compiled for.  That `pip` is in `/home/pi` implies you've installed stuff that isn't from the buster repo.  If that was for the wrong platform, there's your problem.

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for your help. I've removed conda as a workaround and use pip3

Answer (score 1):

**Illegal instruction** is what you get if you try to execute a binary compiled for, eg.,  x86(-64), so almost certainly that's what's happened.

Which implies the miniconda installer is to blame.  To confirm the premise, you need to find the binaries that `pip` and `conda` are trying to execute -- `conda` may be itself an executable, I'm not familiar with it.  You can then examine these with `file`; here's an example of what I mean using a relatively stock RpiOS 64-bit:

```
> file (which pip)
/usr/bin/pip: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

This is how we know `pip` is actually a python script and not a binary executable file.  The first thing in the script is of course `#!/usr/bin/python`, so:

```
> file (which python)
/usr/bin/python: symbolic link to python2

> file (which python2)
/usr/bin/python2: symbolic link to python2.7

> file (which python2.7)
/usr/bin/python2.7: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked ...
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here I've followed a set of symlinks to the actual binary. Here's the same thing from an x86-64 desktop python3:

```
> file (which python3.9)
/usr/bin/python3.9: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked ...
                                                   ^^^^^^
```

Notice the  platform architecture is shown: "ARM aarch64" and "x86-64".

If what you get isn't the former, that's what's wrong. Otherwise, try:

```
> sudo apt install strace
[ ... ]
> strace pip
```

`strace` produces copious output detailing the system calls that are being made.  Paste the last 25 lines into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Miniconda doesn't work on RPI, try miniforge: I work with https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).